# getbitmap makes app slow

Tags: android, bitmap

I used `getBitmap` like `bitmap = textureView.getBitmap(width_bit, height_bit);`
but it loops in camera2api's Highspeedcapturesession which can capture up to 120fps. So lots of bitmap can be created per second.

The problem is that after i run the app, time goes on, it goes very slow and preview texture freezes.

How can I solve this slowing down problem?

(I think the getbitmap saves too lots of bitmap in buffer. If this rights, how can i release several bitmap while running app?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Build your bitmap in a `AsyncTask`

This way your job will not overload the main thread:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
     protected void onPreExecute() {
         // Runs on the UI thread before doInBackground
         // Good for toggling visibility of a progress indicator
         progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
     }

     protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
         // Some long-running task like downloading an image.
         Bitmap = downloadImageFromUrl(strings[0]);
         return someBitmap;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Progress... values) {
        // Executes whenever publishProgress is called from doInBackground
        // Used to update the progress indicator
        progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
     }  

     protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
         // This method is executed in the UIThread
         // with access to the result of the long running task
         imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
         // Hide the progress bar
         progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
     }
}
```

And when you need to run something in the maint thread again use this:

```
MyActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           //Your code to run in GUI thread here
        }//public void run() {
});
```

Comment: Thanks i'll try this.

Comment: I tried lots of times but it makes error. Because getting bitmap from textureview should be executed in UI Thread. So any other way to try? I hope there it is.... thanks

Comment: Get the bitmap before calling the async task, then do the heavy job in that task. This solve your problem?